# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I'm facing with an error: **"unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"** 
when I insert new data in coreData and reload my tableview, I recall this function

```
  var unique = [String]()
  var loadMovie = [String:[Movie]]()


 func insertMovie(movie : Movie) {
    let genre = movie.genre!
    if unique.contains(genre) {
        loadMovie[genre]!.append(movie)
    } else {
        unique.append(genre)
        loadMovie[genre] = [movie]
    }
}
```

and fetch data:

```
 func fetchAndSetResults() {
    let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = app.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest  = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Movie")

    do {
        let movies = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Movie]
        loadMovie.removeAll()
        for movie in movies {
        insertMovie(movie)
        }
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print(err.debugDescription)
    }
}
```

and the app crushes for the error mentioned above on line: "            loadMovie[genre]!.append(movie)" but if I reload app, my data are stored and visible in tableview. What's the problem?

Comment: Did you search Stack Overflow for existing answers?

Comment: Read up on _optional binding_, and _optionals_ in general: a key concept in Swift, one that I suspect you have not fully grasped, seeing your forced unwrappings `... = movie.genre!`, and `... loadMovie[genre]!`. Note that you shouldn't trust the compiler blindly when it asks you to unwrap optionals: in its current state, it usually just asks if you want to perform a forced unwrapping (`!`), which is, generally, a bad advice from the compiler. I personally suspect that a large part of all the _"unexpectedly found nil ..."_ questions here on SO are based on trust to saneness of compiler advice.

Comment: In the solution I proposed `genre` is non-optional. You changed that and that causes the error. For your purpose to use `genre` as a section identifier you need a non-optional value.

Comment: Yes,  but if I don't put "!"  - I receive error: "Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped: did You mean to use "!" or "?"?  on all line. that's why I put '!'

Comment: @user1679705 Again: do not trust the compiler advice here, but instead read up on e.g. [optional binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html). I urge you to grasp the concept of optionals and how to _safely_ unwrap them before proceeding on your Swift journey (this will most likely save you much time and let you avoid many common swift beginner pitfalls).

Comment: You changed the declaration in the `Movie` class, that's the issue. Core Data supports also non-optional attributes.

Comment: @dfri `genre` is supposed to be a non-optional type

Comment: @vadian I have no idea what the background of this question is (it seems it stems from a prior question, judging from your comments to each other), but in the context of _this_ question, I believe it's important feedback to the OP is to not forcibly unwrap optionals, and to attempt to grasp the basic concept of optionals in Swift.

Comment: @dfri The concept of Swift is to use non-optional types as much as possible. Yes, the question is related to a prior one where `genre` was declared as non-optional.

Comment: @vadian However you turn it I don't think we can say that optionals is not an important _concept_ in Swift, even if it's perhaps _best practice_ to use non-optional types as much as possible (I wont say yes or no as to this; I use optionals a lot, but perhaps that is my own lacking...). The latter should not exclude pointing out the former, or we'll possible have another question from the OP, sooner or later, regarding forcibly unwrapping optionals. Your feedback on the specifics of class/... `Movie` is likely valuable for the OP to solve this question; but optionals is very relevant here.

Comment: Movie entity is: @NSManaged var genre: String?   from CoreData I don't understand where the error is

Comment: As mentioned before, Core Data supports also non-optional attributes, you can change that in the Attribute Inspector and you have to change also the type to implicit unwrapped optional (String!)  in the `NSManagedObject` subclass. In your design it's completely meaningless to declare `genre` as optional because each `Movie` item without a genre is ignored to be inserted into the table view data source.

Answer (score 0):

you unwrapped optional variable means you just resolving the compile time error only. In swift you unwrapping the variable means it is represents that variable won't get the nil.You are just telling to the compiler .But now you are getting the nil (Run time Error) you need to handle this by using Optional Binding.

```
  if let movies = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
{
            loadMovie.removeAll()
}
```

Comment: what I want to do is to avoid the nil error and not to manage it. when I close the view "add Movie" and recall the func "fetchAndSetResults" on my table the error of nil value cames on loadMovie.removeAll(). in fact if I cancel this line, I have no error but all movies will be duplicated! I need to avoid this.

Comment: Listen this first you understand easily  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1s9ZjDkSN0

Answer (score 0):

Your variable *loadMovie* is a Dictionary with Strings as the keys and Arrays of *Movies* as what is stored for each key. If you are getting the error **"unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"** for line  *" loadMovie[genre]!.append(movie)"* it means without a doubt the String called **genre** is sometimes not a stored as a key in your *loadMovie* Dictionary.

Use the code below to first make sure you can get the Array stored for that key (stored in the *genre* string), and if you can't then print out the String so you can debug, to find out what key is missing.

```
var unique = [String]()
var loadMovie = [String:[Movie]]()

func insertMovie(movie : Movie) {
    let genre = movie.genre!
    if unique.contains(genre) {
        if let genreArray = loadMovie[genre]{
            genreArray.append(movie)
        } else {
            NSLog("The missing genre: \(genre)")
        }
    } else {
        unique.append(genre)
        loadMovie[genre] = [movie]
    }
}
```

Anytime you want a value that could be nil (not there) you can use the **if/let** pattern above. So for your second question in the comments you could replace *return loadMovie[genre].count* with:

```
 if let genreArray = loadMovie[genre]{
     return genreArray.count
 } else {
     return 0  // zero because there are no items 
 }
```

There are other ways too. You should checkout a good basic swift tutorial like: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/

If you look at the section on optionals this should all be more clear. Here at stack overflow you are generally expected to first have tried to find out answers for yourself, and understand the basic theory. Unfortunately, that is why you are getting so many down votes. I hope this has helped.

If this has helped you please accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Hi the function now runs but the error appears when the app creates the section:  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  let genre = unique[section] <---- HERE SAME ERROR 
  return loadMovie[genre]!.count
}

Comment: because  the *genre* String is used as a key for the *loadMovie* Dictionary any time you try to use *genre* where that key is not found in the dictionary, *nil* is going to be returned.  In Swift when you 'force unwrap' a nil value (when you use the exclamation point: !) your app is going to crash.  You are using a key that doesn't have a value.  You need to first check and then return zero if it is nil.

Comment: yes but I don't want that genre is optional, because, as @vadian said, it's nonsense. Core Data gives this tribute himself and I can't change genre to non-optional. How can I do that? I can't find anything to resolve